# use a bootstrap modal without making a seperate controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using a [bootstrap modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Controller.js -

```
    $scope.open = function() {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/template.html',
        controller: 'controller2',
        resolve: {
            items: function() {
                return $scope.values;
            }
        }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function(values) {
        $scope.new_value = values;
    }, function() {

    });
};
```

I don't want to create a new controller since the modal should show values which are constantly changing in the current controller. What should I pass in place of controller2 if I modal to be in the same controller?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the scope option instead of the controller:

```
$scope.open = function() {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/template.html',
        scope: $scope,
        resolve: {
            items: function() {
                return $scope.values;
            }
        }
});
modalInstance.result.then(function(values) {
        $scope.new_value = values;
    }, function() {

    });
};
```